# Почему при сохранении проекта в другом месте на компьютере, в IDE местоположение не меняется

Tags: delphi

Почему при сохранении делфи проекта на рабочем столе, например, его местоположение в среде никак не меняется и все модули хранятся все в прежнем месте?[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все у вас верно, на рабочем столе в папке учеба\ОАИП\Курсач

Comment: Странно конечно, попробуйте открыть проект что находится в папке `Курсач`. Дерево должно отобразится без полного пути.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена